# Want to Store and Access Live Access Database Online

Tags: ms-access

I have been trying to make an Inventory Management System. I have made the database on Access but I want the database to run online so that people from remote areas with different access levels can modify it in real time.

Is there a way I can store the .accdb file with access restriction? Or is there any online service hosting live databases of MS Access?

Comment: Don't do this for performance and security reasons. Is a `terminal server` with a `vpn` connection an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your infrastructure. The simplest (but worst as far as performance) is to set up VPN connections for remote users. Event better if you have the capability use Remote Web Workplace or a Remote Desktop server. Finally put all the tables on SQL Server or MySQL and distribute the front end. With any of these, as with any Internet facing service, you have to be very careful with your security precautions but it is possible to do any of these with adequate security.

If you know only one user will be working at it at a time you can use something like DropBox, Google drive or SkyDrive but that will not work if you want more than one user at a time. Access will not be able to "combine" the changes from multiple user accessing it this way.